# opencl constant memory or value arguments

Tags: opencl

In OpenCL you can pass a buffer to a kernel via clSetKernelArg and mark that buffer as __constant in the kernel.  Alternatively, you can also use clSetKernelArg to pass a value type.

My question is, where does the value type live?  Does the API create a constant buffer behind the scenes?  Does the API generate a special shader with those values as constant literals?

I'm just curious because I come from a direct3d/opengl background, and constants always had to be passed through constant buffers.  So I'm wondering how passing a type by value as an argument works under the hood.

Comment: I've also been curious where kernel parameters end up on the GPU. Since there is a device property "Max size of kernel arguments" (CL_DEVICE_MAX_PARAMETER_SIZE) which is minimally 256 bytes (but usually more like 1K) I've assumed that it's just a fixed-size amount of memory that a kernel has access to, not unlike constant memory.